# adding max length attribute to ionic text field

Tags: angular, ionic2

how do i set **max length** for ionic2 text field. I am able to set for '**tel**' field but not for **text** field.

```
<ion-input maxlength="12" type="tel">
```

but the following one not working,

```
<ion-input maxlength="12" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the Angular Forms like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="addItemForm">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="itemName"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Items</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="quantity" type="number" [(ngModel)]="itemQuantity"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

And in the ts file:

```
this.addItemForm = new FormGroup({
    quantity: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
    ]),
    name: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(20),
        Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')
   ])
});
```

With this `Validators.maxLength(20)` you can set the maxlength and make custom validations.

Hope this can help you :)

PD: you can read more info [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)